# Какие технологии можно использовать для написания вк бота?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Всем доброго времени суток, мне нужно писать бота для ВК, опыт работы с ботами для телеги имею (писал их с помощью pytelegrambotapi), но вот какую либу юзать для вк понятия не имею, так как в сети нет точного едино-принятого решения (может я не нашел). Бот мой должен иметь нехилый функционал, в основном постоянная работа с БД. Хочу, чтобы все работало максимально быстро, но возникает вопрос - это дело самого кода и навыков программиста, либо же и либа важную роль играет?
Буду рад за любую помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительно полезных и нужных библиотек для работы с vk api нет. Преимущество от их использования сомнительно, они особо ничего не дают. Если у вас большое приложение, то имеет смысл написать свои методы и функции, это не сильно увеличит размер вашего кода, но вам будет удобнее работать. А вообще библиотека это лишь ваш выбор. Кого-то раздражают готовые функции, которые невозможно переписать под себя, кому-то нравится, кто-то хочет использовать это, кто-другое тут ваш выбор. Никакого преимущества в скорости и ещё в чём-либо это не даст.

Для высокой скорости пишите асинхронный код, всё остальное никак не ускорит ваш сервер. Общепринятая бд для python - PostgreSQL. Библиотека для асинхронной работы с этой БД в python - asyncpg. Если вам не нужна высокая производительно и количество запросов вряд ли перевалит за 100 в секунду, то можно писать обычный синхронный код и использовать psycopg2 для работы с БД.

Comment: `sqlalchemy` + `psycopg` одно удовольствие.

Comment: @icYFTL выбор каждого, я пробовал, мне не понравилось, использование таких библиотек потом сильно мешает в других языках и очень сильно не хватает знания SQL